# Receiving CORS error with an axios call to SpringBoot backend

Tags: spring-boot, axios, cors

I'm calling to a Springboot backend with an axios call and for reason I'm getting a cors error even though I thought I had it configured correctly.

My Vue frontend is on localhost:3000
And my springboot backend is on localhost: 8080

Receiving this when I run it on curl -

```
~ % curl -I http://localhost:8080/api/v1/login
HTTP/1.1 405 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Allow: POST
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 17 Mar 2021 16:08:29 GMT
```

WebSecurityConfig -

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:8080"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll();
}
```

CORSConfig.java -

```
@Configuration
public class CORSConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest request= (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
        response.setIntHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", 3600);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

Axios call -

```
  submit() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.set("email", this.email)
    formData.set("password", this.password)
    formData.set("staySignedIn", this.staySignedIn)
    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/login", formData,
        {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
        .then(function (res) {
          if (res.data.code === 200) {
            this.router.push('/dashboard')
          } else {
            console.log(res.data.code);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following class to your project and let spring do the work. You can find more on this here :- [spring-enable-cors](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DemoCORSFilter implements Filter {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoCORSFilter.class);

public DemoCORSFilter () {
    log.info("DemoCORSFilter init");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

}
```